# When I am rendering a a page the page is getting unresponsive

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

In my project i have simple  two components Album and card when  i try to render the card components in app.js  the page never loads and it gives me error that that the page is becoming unresponsive and when i comment the card the page loads perfectly i have not did anything big so far i have just creatd a navbar and wanted to have a card in there

my app.js

```
import Album from './components/Album';
// import Card from './components/Card';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Album/>
    {/* <Card/> */}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my album.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container,Navbar,Nav,NavDropdown,FormControl,Form,Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
// import  "./style.css";

const Album = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Container>
    <Navbar.Brand href="#">Amna Gallery</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarScroll" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarScroll">
      <Nav
        className="me-auto my-2 my-lg-0"
        style={{ maxHeight: '100px' }}
        navbarScroll
      >
        <Nav.Link href="#action1">Home</Nav.Link>
        <NavDropdown title="Link" id="navbarScrollingDropdown">
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action3">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action4">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
          <NavDropdown.Divider />
          <NavDropdown.Item href="#action5">
            Something else here
          </NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
      <Form className="d-flex">
        <FormControl
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          className="me-2"
          aria-label="Search"
        />
        <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
      </Form>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
        </>
    )
}

export default Album
```

my card.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Card = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

after using the first answer given getting this error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of your component from 'Card' to something else since you are already importing the bootstrap Card in the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not importing `Card` in your `Card.js`

```
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Comment: Its not working i have shared the error which i get after uing the solution

Comment: You should change your component name. Try with a name something like CardComponent

Comment: this work i just did not notice it thanks

Comment: Why you changed accepted answer? I gave the first answer to solve your problem and can not see some different solution in other answer? @sarangkkl

Comment: I dont know it affects you sorry i thought that will also help the other person for repution dont know that it affect you badly soory how to make it reverse

Answer (score 1):

Within the same file, two const(Component) cannot have the same name.
you have 2 option

1. Change the name of your component from Card to MyCard.
2. import { Button, Card as BTCard } from 'react-bootstrap' and use BTCard in your Card component

Code for reference
option 1: MyCard.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button,Card } from 'react-bootstrap'

const MyCard = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyCard
```

option 2: Rename the Card component of Boostrap

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Card as BTCard } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Card = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <BTCard style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
  <BTCard.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <BTCard.Body>
    <BTCard.Title>Card Title</BTCard.Title>
    <BTCard.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </BTCard.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </BTCard.Body>
</BTCard>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```